# How to load WooCommerce cross sell and cart-collaterals inside one div

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to load the WooCommerce `.cross-sells` div inside a custom div named `.cart-collaterals-cross-sell` which already includes the `.cart-collaterals elements`, so that i can style them better in one row. At the moment the `.cross-sells` is loaded by the cross-sells.php and  i tried to implement the code of it into the cart.php, so that i have both functions in one file and that i could put them inside the same div. Problem is that the cross sells doesn't load when i copy the code inside the cart.php

That's the original code of the cart.php which includes already the `.cart-collaterals`

```
<div class="cart-collaterals-cross-sell">
<div class="cart-collaterals">

    <h2><?php _e( 'Cart totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php if ( ! is_ajax() && wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
        <div class="nm-coupon-wrap">
            <div class="nm-coupon-inner">
                <a href="#" id="nm-coupon-btn"><?php esc_html_e( 'Gutschein', 'nm-framework' ); ?></a>

                <div class="nm-coupon">
                    <input type="text" id="nm-coupon-code" class="input-text" name="nm_coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <input type="submit" id="nm-apply-coupon-btn" class="button border" name="nm_apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
        /**
         * Cart collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
    ?>

</div>
</div>
```

And that's the way i tried it. What am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="cart-collaterals-cross-sell">
<div class="cart-collaterals">

    <h2><?php _e( 'Cart totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php if ( ! is_ajax() && wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
        <div class="nm-coupon-wrap">
            <div class="nm-coupon-inner">
                <a href="#" id="nm-coupon-btn"><?php esc_html_e( 'Gutschein', 'nm-framework' ); ?></a>

                <div class="nm-coupon">
                    <input type="text" id="nm-coupon-code" class="input-text" name="nm_coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <input type="submit" id="nm-apply-coupon-btn" class="button border" name="nm_apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
        /**
         * Cart collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
    ?>

</div>
    <div class="cross-sells">

        <h2><?php _e( 'You may be interested in&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $cross_sells as $cross_sell ) : ?>

                <?php
                    $post_object = get_post( $cross_sell->get_id() );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following two functions

1. For Cart collaterals ==> `woocommerce_cart_totals();`
2. For Cross Sells =======> `woocommerce_cross_sell_display();`

Try Using following code I am providing here:

```
<div class="cart-collaterals-cross-sell">
<div class="cart-collaterals">

    <h2><?php _e( 'Cart totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php if ( ! is_ajax() && wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
        <div class="nm-coupon-wrap">
            <div class="nm-coupon-inner">
                <a href="#" id="nm-coupon-btn"><?php esc_html_e( 'Gutschein', 'nm-framework' ); ?></a>

                <div class="nm-coupon">
                    <input type="text" id="nm-coupon-code" class="input-text" name="nm_coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <input type="submit" id="nm-apply-coupon-btn" class="button border" name="nm_apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
        /**
         * Cart collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        //do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
        woocommerce_cart_totals();
    ?>

</div>
    <div class="cross-sells">

        <?php woocommerce_cross_sell_display(); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```